# Comparison test for convergence/divergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The following true or false question's answer is false.

Since $0\leq \frac{e^{arctan(x)}}{x^2} \leq \frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}}{x^2}$ for all $0 < x \leq1$ and $ \int^{1}_{0} \frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}}{x^2}\, \mathrm dx$ is convergent, it follows from the comparison test that $ \int^{1}_{0} \frac{e^{arctan(x)}}{x^2}\, \mathrm dx $ is convergent.

Why is this false? Surely because $0\leq g(x)\leq f(x)$ with $f(x)$ is convergent this should make the statement true? What am I not understanding correctly? All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you saying $\int_0^1 dx/x^2$ is convergent? Try computing it!

Comment: that is the point... $\int_0^1 e^{\pi/4}/x^2 \,dx$ is not convergent.

Comment: $$ \frac{e^{\mathrm{arctan}(x)}}{x^2} \; \mathop{\sim} \limits_{x \to 0} \; \frac{1}{x^2} $$

and $x \mapsto 1/x^2$ is not integrable on $]0,1]$.